# How to Replace all strings in Javascript? In particular with Combination of special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In JavaScript, I want to replace all `@$£` in a string.

```
var myString="Dinesh @$£ is @$£";
```

Like this, I am not able to replace `@$#` either.

I tried this:

```
myString.replace(/@$£/g, "|");
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Memdy/

```
var myString="test @$£ is @$£";
var result = myString.replace(/@\$£/g, "|");;
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape `$`, which is "end of line" symbol:

```
myString.replace(/@\$£/g, "|");
```

Comment: Both are not working for me...I think the reason for the issue is '£'...Can Plz you help me?

Comment: Just tried this in chrome's console: `"Dinesh @$£ is @$£".replace(/@\$£/g, "|") -> "Dinesh | is |"`

Answer (score 1):

try like this

var temp = "Dinesh @$£ is @$£";

temp =  temp.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'');

document.write(temp);

Answer (score 0):

```
  "Dinesh @$£ is @$£".replace(/@\$£/g, "|");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AF77K/

Answer (score 0):

$ has a special meaning in regular expressions. You must add a backslash before the $ to search for a $ symbol:

```
myString.replace(/@\$£/g, "|");
```

This will also work if you don't know what the special characters in the string may be:

```
myString.split('@$£').join("|");
```

Comment: Both are not working for me...I think the reason for the issue is '£'...Can you help me?